Salesforce SOAP API Query Operation - Invalid Session ID Error
I am attempting to perform a SOAP query operation against the Salesforce SOAP API to retrieve data from the ConnectedApplication object. However, each time I try to execute the query, I receive an "INVALID_SESSION_ID" error.
The bearer token I use asession ID is fresh and valid by performing REST API calls successfully with it, and I am using the correct endpoint for my Salesforce org's instance(the one i extracted from /services/oauth2/userinfo response).
Here is the nodejs code where I perform auth:
function createJwt(consumerKey, username, privateKey) {
    const issuedAt = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const exp = issuedAt + 300;
  
    return jwt.sign({
      iss: consumerKey,
      sub: username,
      aud: loginUrl,
      exp: exp
    }, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
  }
  
  // Authenticate using JWT Bearer Token Flow
  async function authenticateUsingJwt() {
    const jwtToken = createJwt(consumerKey, username, privateKey);
  
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${loginUrl}/services/oauth2/token`, null, {
        params: {
          grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
          assertion: jwtToken
        }
      });
      console.log('Successfully connected to Salesforce!');
      return response.data.access_token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to authenticate:', error.message);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  
  (async () => {
      try {
      const accessToken = await authenticateUsingJwt();
      console.log('Access Token:', accessToken);
      
      // Initialize connection with the access token
      const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
          instanceUrl: 'https://myorg-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com',
          accessToken: accessToken,
        version: '60.0'
    });
    const result = await conn.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM ConnectedApplication'); //this is working properly
    const appData = await conn.metadata.read('ConnectedApp', connectedApps[0]); //and this is throwing sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID error
} catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
}
})();

The same error happens when I try to form soap request manually in hoppscotch(postman).
Here's the request body:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <SessionHeader xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
      <sessionId>eyJ0bmsiOiJjb3JlL3Byb2QvMDBEMDcwMDAwMDBZWEZCRUE0IiwidmVyIjoiMS4wIiwia2lkIjoiQ09SRV9BVEpXVC4wMEQwNzAwMDAwMFlYRkIuMTcxMjc1NDkzNzM4MiIsInR0eSI6InNmZGMtY29yZS10b2tlbiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzY3AiOiJhcGkiLCJhdWQiOlsiaHR0cHM6Ly9lbGVtZW50c2VuZy1kZXYtZWQuZGV2ZWxvcC5teS5zYWxlc2ZvcmNlLmNvbSJdLCJzdWIiOiJ1aWQ6MDA1MDcwMDAwMDRlcXM1QUFBIiwibmJmIjoxNzEyODI3NTM5LCJtdHkiOiJvYXV0aCIsInJvbGVzIjpbXSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9lbGVtZW50c2VuZy1kZXYtZWQuZGV2ZWxvcC5teS5zYWxlc2ZvcmNlLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTcxMjgyNzg1NCwiaWF0IjoxNzEyODI3NTU0LCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiIzTVZHOVhMZnNKM01RTHZ3dlZXYnBwTWw0dm1tRDJvcy5VZTBUb2FzV05ER09fMW8wcHYzUFVRVHFTS0gxQVFJem5VQm00MG9ZMm9fU1NobTI4U3lDIn0.adhdb92olQnokWHA7S6m4jmpRyhDgU-CPMNFyBAfPPZwp2xdJ1wYcuHKkOGXPrlftlhMjdBm4rx11Smd56ocWFxNMWHZPFOzcml2SBUAB4DDFVoYoSUgmDf7C-qisgb4iVigulNZzoFfw4ZHCHw6Md4dXCSAnnIjPRejBO1uqtCpsA80cqLhAv724kJCfnoDXBkcu8sbAhtc1P2zz9ulkronSTRDqiWP2bnCb2BDZECetepXCnA6fRbFyk-9ysrLgGXHkj8F3rRsahXvltHBk1ajudgn2HTugXPe2DgDaN6JPkb5DqftXd5sCWRvnTDqDZARqjrAmRIzHp03DgtKSw</sessionId>
    </SessionHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <readMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
      <type>ConnectedApp</type>
      <fullNames>myapp</fullNames>
    </readMetadata>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

What I've tried:

Confirming that the user whose session ID I'm using has the necessary permissions for API access.
Double-checking the session ID is valid by performing a REST API call successfully.
Messing around with request and token format in hoppcsotch(postman)

I'm not sure whether JWT token can be used as a session ID for auth, I was told so by ChatGPT.
Any clues and explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Does this answer your question? SOAP API Connection with Access Token

You have an access token rather than a session ID, they're not the same thing.

@identigral

You have an access token rather than a session ID, they're not the same thing.

That's the valid point. Thank you
Any advice on how to obtain a session ID out of it? Or must I perform the soap auth separately?

Ok. I ended up with username-password auth for the soap api. For the jsforce library it is necessary to execute conn.login(username, password); after the connection is established.
